# How to bind <Tab> key press in Perl Tk?

Tags: perl

I am looking for the code syntax to bind a `<Tab`> keypress event to a Perl Tk Widget.

Reading through the documentation, I saw i can bind `<Control>` and `<Alt>` (and any combination), but couldn't find the `<Tab>` key binding.

I've tried `...->bind('<Tab>', sub{...});` but it didn't work.

How to bind it?

Comment: See also [Python Tkinter - recovering original default key binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468106/python-tkinter-recovering-original-default-key-binding)

Comment: @HåkonHægland: is the link desribing perl or python? i am looking into perl..

Comment: @NirMH: The link uses the Python language. But the Tk API is pretty uniform and you should be able to interpret what is written there in Perl terms. Or did you want the exact code written for you?

Comment: @Borodin: i just wanted to confirm exactly what you've said. that Tk API is not different for Python. thanks - i can handle the language translation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging with this issue for a while, and exploring all good advice provided in the comments. I've found out the best way to achieve my purpose is to derive the Widget and create my own custom widget, and use OOP override techniques to control the behavior.

This works like charm.

So for `Tk::Text`, for example, the native `<Tab>` event is bind to

```
$mw->bind($class,'<Tab>', 'insertTab');

sub insertTab
{
     my ($w) = @_;
     $w->Insert("\t");
     $w->focus;
     $w->break
}
```

And by deriving from `Tk::Text` widget to my own `Tk::myText` widget, I was able to override the `insertTab` method as follows:

```
sub insertTab
{
    my ($w) = @_;

    // <-- place my stuff here 
    // <-- to be executed first

    $w->SUPER::insertTab();  // <-- then call the original <Tab> handler from the parent
}
```